# Creating DbContext.Set<Entity> using reflection

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1, entity-framework-migrations

```
myDbContext: DbContext
{
  DbSet<Person> {get;set;}
  //So many domain 
}
```

So I used `Set<T> approch`

```
myDbContext: DbContext
{
   pubilc DbSet<T> Set<Person> table()
   {
      return Set<T>
   }
}
```

But now migration is not generating changes or tables

Comment: A context needs a predefined set of DbSet properties for it to be able to create the database, how else would it know what to do?

Comment: Is there any way we can defined properties do something using reflection

Comment: No, this question really doesn't make any sense. Why are you trying to do this? You're asking for a context with an unknown definition but still want the known definition so it can use migrations.

Comment: Use one rule for indent

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to improve, I only see compiling code turned into non-compiling code. It's is not clear what you're asking.